# TypeScript implicit any error with Superagent

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, superagent

I am using `superagent` in a TypeScript project and have installed `@types/superagent` but am seeing a type error I don't understand. Given the following...

```
const myRequest = request
  .get('/path/to/api')
  .end((err, res) => {
    // Do stuff with err and res
  })
```

I get these errors for `err` and `res`:
`Parameter 'err' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`
`Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`

But at the same time TypeScript does seem to know the types of these variables because when I hover on them in VSCode it shows the correct types from `@types/superagent`, as can be seen in the below image.

[image: VSCode hover]

In the image it shows that it is correctly getting the type of `res` as `request.Response` from `@types/superagent`.

Therefore I don't understand why I am getting these implicit type errors. Is anybody able to explain this to a TypeScript newbie? Thanks :)

Comment: Actually that's not a newbie thing.  It's truly bizarre if I understand you correctly, because it's simultaneously telling you it knows the type and doesn't know the type.  Just to confirm, that screenshot is all one piece, right?  Not assembled from different places?  Also, what do you see if you hover over the `.end`?

Comment: Note that VSCode has its own built-in version of TypeScript which it uses to give that inline type info.  By default, it's different from the one you have on disk.  Have you tried restarting VSCode?  That will force it to rescan all the imports for type info.

Comment: i do believe that you have set  'res:requset.Response' somewhere in your code

Comment: @Mr.AF https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQUwE4ApgBciuKRAzlNjGAOYA0iARkWCALaM4CUiAvAHyIAbnBgATHgG9EAXwBQc1Bhy5cALwYAPHgMTSZXANxA typescript should be able to infer it, no need to repeat it twice.

Comment: @zerkms yea it did and show error right now.

Comment: @Mr.AF it should not have, see my example.

Comment: @zerkms i got yea , you are right , if parameter set to any there should be not any error right?

Comment: @Mr.AF If you explicitly type an argument of a callback as `any` it still would pass since those 2 function types would be still compatible.

Comment: @user2740650 Yes the screenshot is all one piece. I have tried restarting VSCode but the errors persist. I also get the errors if I run TypeScript from the command line. When hovering on `.end` it shows the correct info extracted from `@types/superagent`. Very weird.

Comment: @Michael I've never seen this before, but I use TypeScript all the time.  Are you able to set up a simple demo link somewhere (like maybe https://jsfiddle.net/)?  That way we can see it in action.

Comment: I am also getting these errors on Bitbucket / Jenkins, despite the fact that VS Code knows the type of the parameter. I wondered if it was caused by overzealous linting. I fixed it by explicitly adding the type, but I'd like to know why it is doing it.

Answer (score -2):

You are not specifying the type of the parameters. Try the following:

```
const myRequest = request
  .get('/path/to/api')
  .end((err, res: request.Response) => {
    // Do stuff with err and res
  })
```

Comment: This does not address the original question: "why I am getting these implicit type errors"

Comment: also the type of `res` is more likely to be the type of object returned from the API